# Why does confirm form resubmission appear in this case?

Tags: php

I have a code like the following:

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])){

$error=0;
//verify if there are any errors (like uncompleted fields)
//if there are errors, $error=1

if($error==0){
//do something then print "DONE";
}
else if($error==1){
//SHOW FORM AGAIN
}
}
else{//IF $_POST["send"] IS NOT SET
//SHOW FORM: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"> etc.
}
```

What happens is that **when I submit the form without any errors and I go back, there is no "Confirm form resubmission" message**, but when submit something **with errors**, then I modify it so there are no errors, then submit and go back, the **"Confirm form resubmission" message appears**.

*Why does that happen? Why doesn't it work the same for both cases?*

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code to look like the below code

```js
<?php
$error = 1;
if(isset($_POST["send"])){

$error=0;
//verify if there are any errors (like uncompleted fields)
//if there are errors, $error=1
} else{    //IF $_POST["send"] IS NOT SET
  
//SHOW FORM: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"> etc.
}

if($error==0){
//do something then print "DONE";
}
elseif($error==1){
//SHOW FORM AGAIN
}

?>
```

But its not a cool code due to the  lack of your information, you need to use first block of if statement for checking `if post is set`  and `the variable $error`  for checking validation.

Comment: Actually I used this and the page does the same thing.